# What is "Optimistic" Asynchronous Operations in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: asynchronous, dynamics-crm

I am learning Dynamics CRM 2015 (differences from prev. versions). My experience is in Dynamics CRM 2011.  Obviously it is a bit of a jump; I am taking some tutorials on YouTube and came across the term "Optimistic" Asynchronous.

I have searched this term and am having a hard time getting the answer that I need.  May somebody explain this to me?  Also, is this a term that is mostly used withing Dynamics CRM.

Thanks!

Comment: youtube link where this optimistic asynchronous operation is mentioned?

Comment: TBH...I've watched over 50 MSDN vids and can't remember the exact one...it was on this list though:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadcrmsupport/archive/2014/12/11/dynamics-crm-2015-new-training-videos.aspx -- I think it was something new in 2015

Comment: looks, the only thing with the word optimistic that comes in my mind related to CRM 2015 is this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn707955.aspx hope it helps

Comment: @GuidoPreite Thanks.  I might of confused "Asynchronous" with "Concurrent"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dynamics CRM excessive usage of workflows can lead to deadlocks frequently occurring in the SQL Server database. I.e. the asyncoperation table tends to grow quickly and multiple concurrent threads processing workflow operation jobs often compete for getting exclusive access to shared database resources.

Database (*pessimistic*) locking tends to scale badly, especially in high traffic transactional systems, so SQL Server 2005 introduced another technique called *optimistic locking*. (Nice explanations can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/TransactionJTA_Overview-Pessimistic_and_optimistic_locking.html) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).) When a record is retrieved from the database a column is included holding a unique time stamp or version number. When this record is to be updated, the database simply checks if its time stamp or version number still remains unchanged. If not, after the original read operation another process apparently has modified the same row, so the update is based on a dirty read and must be cancelled and the transaction is rolled back.

**Dynamics CRM 2015 Update 1** introduced optimistic concurrency for entities through RowVersion attributes, as you can read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932125(v=crm.7).aspx).

Comment: This is possibly one of the best answers I have received on here.